# How to boot the ISO Ubuntu from DVD?

Tags: system-installation, iso

I have burned the ISO file of Ubuntu to a DVD. But when I tried to install the OS on restarting the computer, the PC just boots into my normal OS and not the DVD.

So how do I get it to boot into my DVD and install?

Comment: You should make sure that the DVD is at the top of the boot order in your BIOS settings.

Comment: What OS do you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable bootable DVD media in your BIOS menu.
Most BIOS menus are activated by pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys just when the system starts.
After altering the BIOS save changes.
Now you should be able to boot through DVD.
If not make sure that in the BIOS DVD is set to boot first than the hard drive.